# Internet Explorer (WM6.5) - How to increase TimeOut limit after page submit?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, timeout, registry, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm testing a webpage that after a submit triggers a very heavy process on the server backend. Unfortunately the processing takes so long that after some 40 seconds Internet explorer displays this error page.

[image]
[image]

This is definitely a timeout error related to Internet Explorer as it is not triggered in other browsers.  Internet Explorer (wm6.5) simply doesn't wait long enough for the response.

I've been trying to find some IE setting, registry key or javascript to increase the timeout limit but with no success. And here I am hoping some veterans may have any suggestions for a workaround.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Start Registry Editor.

Locate the following subkey:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

In this subkey, add a ReceiveTimeout DWORD entry that has a value of ()*1000. For example, if you want the time-out duration to be 8 minutes, set the value of the ReceiveTimeout entry to 480000 (<480>*1000).

There is also a keep_alive setting on the SAP side:
https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw73ehp1/7.31.19/en-US/48/88b52977323cb8e10000000a42189d/content.htm?no_cache=true

Comment: Hi and thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately I already tried ReceiveTimeout, SendTimeout dwords with no sucess.

Comment: The eroor you get is caused by SAP directs to a web page that is not yet ready. Possibly a higher keep_alive setting in ITS? may help. OTOS: hwat happens, when you try this from  a desktop browser? Possibly you need to prepare an interim page that is showing as long as the report is not yet ready and then offers a link to the report.

Comment: Hi @josef. This does not happen with any other browsers, desktop or installed in the device. This is clearly specific to IE6 on WM6.5. We are now considering abandoning IE6 and buy licenses to a proper industrial browser.

Comment: Be aware of the 'industrial browsers' are mostly programmed on top of the existing engine (IE6 or IE6 in PIE mode). So this will not help. The only real different browsers I know for WM6 are by ZetaKey and Opera (Firefox did not scale well and I think is abandoned long time ago). ZetaKey Browser uses it's own HTML5 like engine and so do old Opera versions (if you are able to find one to download). If you own a Zebra Windows Mobile device, you may use there HTML5 browser.

Comment: Hi @josef. Using the same engine doesn't necessarily mean it actually uses the system's Internet Explorer config. All IE based browsers that I've tried actually use a separate version of the renderer, so even if the renderer is the same it's not bound by the system's IE config. One such browser is CETerm. HTML5 browsers available for Windows Mobile are mostly based on a very old port of webkit and carry their own set of issues.

Comment: Correct, although another Browser based on IE6 engine does not implicit mean the 'browser' uses the same setiings. But most programmers are lazy and do not add features they do not care. And yes, you are also right with HTML5 brosers for WM6.x, they are based on old webkit engines but most offer more options to set than you can do with IE6 based ones (ie CETerm or now VelocityCE does not offer timeout settings). Did you try ZeatKey's browser?